# Java script and lightbox close button

Tags: javascript, lightbox

i have added a light box function to my web page. everything works. so when i click on an image it goes bigger...

my problem is that there is no close button. how do i get it to close without having to click back.

Here is my code for the light box

```
window.onload = setupLightbox;

var lightboxOverlay;
var lightboxImage;

function setupLightbox() {
for (i in document.links) {

if(document.links[i].rel == "lightbox"){
document.links[i].onclick = showLightbox;

}

}   

}

function showLightbox() {
lightboxOverlay = document.createElement("div");
lightboxImage = document.createElement("img");

lightboxOverlay.style.position = "fixed";
lightboxOverlay.style.top = lightboxOverlay.style.left ="0";
lightboxOverlay.style.width = lightboxOverlay.style.height ="100%";
lightboxOverlay.style.background = "#000";
lightboxOverlay.style.opacity = "0.5";
lightboxOverlay.style.filter = "alpha(opacity = 50)";


document.body.appendChild(lightboxOve…

lightboxImage.onload = showImage;
lightboxOverlay.onclick = closeLightbox;

 lightboxImage.src = this.href;

return false;


}

function showImage(){

lightboxImage.style.position = "fixed";
lightboxImage.style.top = lightboxImage.style.left = "50%";
lightboxImage.style.marginLeft = -lightboxImage.width/2 + "px";
lightboxImage.style.marginTop = -lightboxImage.width/2 + "px";
lightboxImage.style.border = "10px solid #fff";
document.body.appendChild(lightboxIma…
}

function closeLightbox(){
lightboxImage.style.opacity = lightboxOverlay.style.opacity = "0";
setTimeout( function() {
lightboxImage.parentNode.removeChild…
lightboxOverlay.parentNode.removeChi…
}, 1);

}
```

Comment: either add a close button, or put a close event on the overlay shim which is basically an overlayed superpositoned div in background (transparent or translucent). Other way might be an escape key press ?? I hope I understood the question correctly

Answer (score 0):

Check the Lightbox should have a css file with it and an image folder too. Specify the css file in the header section so that it can find the image.